# How to display values of 2d array in QML?

Tags: javascript, arrays, qt, qml

So I created a property in the root element of my qml and filled it with JavaScript as a 2d array. I did it this way:

```
property var cars: {

    var carList = new Array(root.numberOfCars)

    for (var i=0;i<root.numberOfCars;i++) {

        var carProperties = new Array(numberOfCarProperties);

        carProperties[root.currentStation] = -1;
        carProperties[root.score] = 100;
        carProperties[root.numberOfErrors] = 0;
        carProperties[root.hasProblem] = false;
        carProperties[root.errorScore] = 0;
        carProperties[root.finished] = false;

        carList[i] = carProperties;
    }
    return carList;
}
```

The values of the array will be changed as the program runs via JavaScript.

I want to display the values of this 2d array in a table and update them when they're changed, in addition to some action buttons that affect the values of the array at it's own row.

I'm just a noob at QML and programming in general, so if this is a very basic question please tell me where can I learn more, since I've found few resources online to learn QML.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain arrays are not the ideal solution if you intend to visualize the data. QML views can use arrays as models, but this is inefficient if you want to reflect internal changes. You either have to force update of the entire view, recreating all view delegates instead of just updating the changed value, or you will have to implement your own mechanism to update changes.

The easiest thing to use would be a `ListModel` element, and rather than implementing properties as an array (bad idea anyway) you can implement them as list element properties:

```
ListModel {
    id: carList 
    ListElement {
        currentStation: -1
        score: 100
        numberOfErrors: 0
        // ...
    }
    ListElement {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The model can be populated declarative as above, or imperatively:

```
carList.append({"currentStation": -1, "score": 100, ...})
```

You also have the usual index access, property access and so on, just [scroll through the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) to get an idea of the interface.

The benefit of this is you will get efficient automatic updates in the view. So you just set up a view and implement a delegate that will serve to visualize and manipulate the data.

Comment: Thank you very much! So then I can use a `for` to populate the `ListModel` any number of times without having to declare each `ListElement` separatedly, right?

Comment: Yes, you can populate the model decalratively or imperatively (like a loop).

Comment: Thank you so much!